# apache PropertiesConfiguration doesn't resolve placeholders

Tags: java, apache-config

Say that I have the following two configuration files:

File 1:

```
key1 = ${common.key1}
key2 = ${common.key2}
```

File 2:

```
common.key1 = value1
common.key2 = value2
```

And I have the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
...
PropertiesConfiguration newConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration();
File configFile1 = new File("...paht to file 1");
File configFile2 = new File("...path to file 2");
newConfig.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
newConfig.load(configFile2);
newConfig.load(configFile1);

Iterator<String> props = newConfig.getKeys();
while (props.hasNext()) {
    String propName = props.next();
    String propValue = newConfig.getProperty(propName).toString();
    System.out.println(propName + " = " + propValue);
}
```

I have the following output:

```
common.key1 = value1
common.key2 = value2
key1 = ${common.key1}
key2 = ${common.key2}
```

Why the placeholders are not resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this page](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation) in the documentation, which says:

> Below is some more information related to variable interpolation users should be aware of:
>
> - ...
> - Variable interpolation is done by all property access methods. **One exception is the generic `getProperty()` method which returns the raw property value.**

And that's exactly what you are using in your code.

The [API docs of `getProperty()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/AbstractConfiguration.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-) mentions this as well:

> Gets a property from the configuration. ... **On this level variable substitution is not yet performed.**

Use other methods available in `PropertiesConfiguration` to get the actual, interpolated value. For example, call `getProperties()` on the `PropertiesConfiguration` to convert it to a `java.util.Properties` object and iterate on that instead.

Comment: Actually I finally realised that getProperty() is not what I needed, I should have called getString() cause this method is able to resolve placeholders and that works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use it in generic way with placeholders substitution like below:

```
config.get(Object.class, propName);
```

Unlike `getProperty` method the `get` method with `Object.class` parameter will return value of original class with variables interpolated.